# Strange behavior of Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013, mmc

I have a Microsoft Management Console 3 Project built in .Net 2.0, Currently I am Using Visual Studio 2010 to build this project and every thing is working fine,

For future I am planning it to move my projects in Visual studio 2013 but I am unable to build project in visual studio 2013

```
The type or namespace name 'ManagementConsole' does not exists in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

**Note:** I did not do any other change in the project

Comment: Do you add the assembly reference for it?

Comment: Yes I did and same project is working fine in visual studio 2010

Comment: I mean, in VS2013 - or even 2010 sometimes, the assembly name could be different. In my case, it is `MMC20` and not `Microsoft.ManagementConsole`.

Comment: Its not giving error in adding reference

Comment: open the old working project with VS 2013 and press update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build the solution in VS 2013, by setting framework 4.0 or framework 4.5.
its work in my case.